# python virtualenv : how to specify base prefix?

Tags: python, virtualenv

As soon as I created new VM instance(google cloud platform compute engine), `firstly I installed python 3.6.2 in /usr/local/bin`

And I set up default python interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3.6.

`$ python -V`
Python 3.6.2

`$ virtualenv --version`
15.1.0

My issue is that **activate script is not created.**

`$ virtualenv myenv`

```
Using base prefix '/usr'  
...  
...  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/juhyun1849/PyVirt/test/bin/python3 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

I want to change **bsse prefix '/usr'** to **/usr/local**.

How can I do that??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Comment: Hi @newbie16, just wanted to confirm how you were able to change this; I am not seeing any success yet